# SLURM-UserCPU output-how to intrepret?

Tags: slurm

I am analysing the CPU usage of my batch script that i ran on a cluster.
I used Sacct with UserCPU to get the relevant output
The output format is very difficult to relate to. I know that it is time -but i dont understand what unit is being used.an example for a job using 20 cores is reported--1206-18:1+

can some one help me understand how much of cpu was used by my job? was 20 cores optimal for my job or should i allocate less.

thanks 
amith

Comment: `--1206-18:1+` doen's looks a proper time string. Anyways, times are usually reported as seconds (when it's a real number) or days-hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds (when reported as a string).

Answer (score 0):

The format Slurm uses for reporting UserCPU is `[days-]hours:minutes:seconds[.microseconds]`. The string you see is truncated because the column width is too small, as indicated by the `+` sign you have at the end of the string.

To see the full string, increase the column width using the  `%NUMBER` format modifier, for instance:

```
sacct --format jobid,usercpu%20
```

Your job seems to have consumed 1206.75 days of CPU, so running on 20 cores for a bit more than 60 days. You will need to compare that number with the one in the wall clock time, i.e. the time reported in the `elapsed` column.

Comment: I ran the job for 15 hours and i dont know how i got this output